# java Socket Connection in Service

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-activity, android-service

I need to make a app that connects to a server using sockets. The Connection needs to be kept alive until the app is closed. I will use it to send bytes to the server. I currently am using a service that I bind to the MainActivity. Below is part of my code. What I have works but after a while I think I lose connection. Can the Android OS be destroying my service to free up memory? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
public class myService  extends Service {


    Socket echoSocket = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream din;
     static  String IPADDRESS=null;

     static int port=0;


    OnCreate()
    {

        echoSocket = new Socket();

        echoSocket.connect(ip,port);


         if(echoSocket.isConnected())
         {
            dos = new DataInputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream) ;
            dos.write("som bytes");
            dos.flush();
         }


    }



}
```

Comment: You don't want to create a service like that. If it crashes its can be a big negative as the android system may not stop it. QUOTE "started service must manage its own lifecycle. That is, the system does not stop or destroy the service unless it must recover system memory and the service continues to run after onStartCommand() returns. So, the service must stop itself by calling stopSelf() or another component can stop it by calling stopService()." -> http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: 'I think I lose connection' *why?* Why do you think that? What are the symptoms? What's the question?

Comment: @EJP I have a function that I call on a button press that pings the server. After a while if I try to ping the the server my button freezes and the app crashes.

Comment: Inadequate. Crashes how? Exception? Stack trace?